# advice needed with prolog cut?

Tags: recursion, prolog, prolog-cut

in this task i have a Prolog database filled with e.g.
edge(1,0)
edge(2,0)
edge(1,3)

an edge signifies that two points are joined.

I am asked to write a function called reach(i,j,k) where i is the start point j is the end point and k is the number of steps you may use.
K is needed to stop the recursion looping e.g.

Suppose the only edge I’ve got goes from 1 to3,and I’m trying to get to 6. Then I can’t get from 1to6 in one go. so I’ll look for somewhere I can get to, and see if I can get from there to 6. The first place I can get to in one go is 3, so I’ll try to get from there to 6.

i have done this as so:

```
    %% Can you get there in one step (need two rules because all links are
%% from smaller to greater, but we may need to get from greater to smaller.

reach1(I, J,_K) :-
    edge(I, J).
reach1(I, J,_K) :-
    edge(J, I).
%% Chhose somewhere you can get to in one step: can you get from there
%% to your target?
reach1(I,J,K) :-
    K>1,
    edge(I, B),
    K1 is K-1,
    reach1(B,J,K1).

reach1(I,J,K) :-
    K>1,
    edge(B, I),
    K1 is K-1, 
    reach1(B,J,K1).
```

this works, however i am stuck with the second part in which we are asked not to use k but to use a "cut" to do this.

does anyone know how to do this or can give me some pointers?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970977/traverse-undirected-graph-in-prolog/3971936#3971936 where the traversal of a graph is discussed. The solution there does not use a cut either but I believe it is far more elegant. Of course you could rewrite that solution to use the cut to prune the backtracking tree once you get to an already visited node.

Comment: I don't follow what it would mean "to do this" but not to use K, since it forms part of the specification of **reach1/3**.  Also, your first two rules, the "single step" cases, should presumably have not `_K` but `1` as the third argument for **reach1**.  A general problem with the finding of paths is how to avoid endless recursion, e.g. going from 1 to 2, back to 1, back to 2, and so forth without ever progressing toward the real target.  Perhaps the original exercise was aimed at exploring various ways of preventing such looping.  It's hard to tell from the present request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cut ensures that once a goal has been resolved in one way, it doesn't look for another way.

example:

```
reach(I, J,_K) :-
    edge(I, J).
```

no cut - if for some reason Prolog backtracks, it will try to reach from I to J another way.
You might feel there's no point reaching this node another way if the simple edge works, and in that case you can do:

```
reach(I, J,_K) :-
    edge(I, J),
    !.
```

which "cuts" any alternative to this goal, but the one Prolog has found.